# building windows form application for "any CPU" doesn't pick up code errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, build

I have no idea about this, I have a c# .net4 project when I build it for x86 or x64 with a deliberate code error it warns me of the error, however when I select "any CPU" it doesn't pick up the error and runs the previous good version!

I have moved the project to another PC and have the same issue!

both PCs are windows 10 and VS2015 express.

any ideas?

Comment: Have you got multiple projects in the solution you are trying to build?
Perhaps the error is in a project that isn't being built for "Any CPU" configuration. Check your configuration manager.

Comment: No, just the one project!

Comment: I'm now just building for x86 as it runs on both 64 and 84 PCs